# Handling Python Text File Exceptions

Tags: python

```
try:
    f1 = open("c:\\temp\\MP11Data1.txt")
    lines = f1.readlines()
    list1 = []
    for line in lines:
        k1 = float(line)
        list1.append(k1)
    f1.close()

except ValueError:
    pass
```

If you replace all data in a text file with float, you must have a ValueError error during the string's accidental change. I want to ignore the string as an exception and make only float appear. What should I do?

[image: "c:\temp\MP11Data1.txt"]

Comment: Maybe add another try/catch around `k1 = float(line)` ?

Comment: The comment above is the right answer

Comment: then what can  i do?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your try-except block is too large. It encompasses the whole scanning of the file. You should split it up to handle errors at different points:

```
lines = [] ## Just for security if there is an IOError.

## First handle the file
try:
    f1 = open("c:\\temp\\MP11Data1.txt")
    lines = f1.readlines()
    f1.close()
except:
    print("The file could not be loaded")

## Now you can scan and process the contents
list1 = []
for line in lines:
    try:
        k1 = float(line)
        list1.append(k1)
    except:
        print("This line did not contain a number: ",line)
```

That way, errors at different points of the program will be handled seperately.